# Atomic update Mutation using Prisma

Tags: mysql, node.js, atomic, prisma

What would be the best way to atomically update a node using its an existing value (get-and-update)?
Seems like the [update node Mutation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/1.20/prisma-graphql-api/reference/mutations-qwe2/#updating-nodes) does not have an option of receiving an update-if-exists function.

Locking the object with a write lock, getting the value, updating it and releasing the lock might work but would cause complexity and lots of faulty code I'm trying to avoid.

I'm using MySql with Prisma connector for node.js with a .prisma datamodel.

Answer (score 2):

Transactions in Prisma aren't implemented yet. However there is some issues opened in their github about this:

- Transactions for multiple operations ([#74](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/74))
- Transactions for long running operations with dependencies between write operations ([#3846](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3846))

Comment: Interesting that on page https://www.prisma.io/docs/understand-prisma/prisma-introduction-what-why-how-j9ff/ there is typed `relational data and transactions.`

Answer (score 1):

[Prisma 2.1.0](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/tag/2.1.0) released the first experimental version of transactions via Promises.

Here is the official documentation [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/transactions)

```
const write1 = prisma.user.create()
const write2 = prisma.post.create()
const write3 = prisma.profile.create()
await prisma.$transaction([write1, write2, write3])
```